# Extract/generate thumbnail of MS Office document if "Save Thumbnail" not selected C#

Tags: c#, shell, bitmap, thumbnails, windows-api-code-pack

I am able to successfully extract thumbnails from files using the Windows API Code Pack:

```
Bitmap shellThumb = sf.Thumbnail.ExtraLargeBitmap;
```

where `sf` is a `ShellFile`.

This works for all files that have a thumbnail generated. But, for example, if a Word document has not been saved with the option "Save Thumbnail" selected, then there will only be an icon generated for this file and not the actual thumbnail/preview.

I would like to know if there is a way to generate a thumbnail for these files without having to save each file manually with that option selected. Specifically, I want a solution in C#? I have searched for this, but have not yet found any solutions in C#.

Many thanks.